# C++: Why is my last input not picked up when I use Ctrl+d to end the input loop?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    vector<double> nums;
    double input;
    while (cin >> input) {
        nums.push_back(input);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
        cout << nums[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When the program runs, I input 3 numbers this way:

```
Enter numbers: 1 2 3
```

and right after I typed `3`, I imediately pressed `ctrl+d` and the `enter`. However, only two numbers are printed.

If right after I type `3`, I pressed `enter, ctrl+d, enter`, then three numbers are printed.

I would like to how how to print all 3 numbers regardless of what key I press first. Thanks in advance.

Comment: simply because ctr^D is after 3

Comment: @Raindrop7 so you're saying there's no way around this? And I must press enter after 3 all the time?

Comment: What happens if you put a space after 3 and before ctrl+d?

Comment: On Linux you need either one CTRL-D at the start of a line or two CTRL-D to signal an EOF condition.

Comment: @Gavin it will print 3 numbers

Comment: @AProgrammer I don't think I understand, can you please elaborate?

Comment: @JSstarter: I suspect that the 3rd number is not being set because `input` is of type `double` and 3 with the EOF marker directly after will not be considered a `double`.

Comment: @Gavin If that's how it works, I'll have to enter after the last input then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your C++ code is fine.  It's the terminal settings in the shell that are causing this.  ^D typed in a Linux terminal (^D implies Unix or a Mac) is not interpreted until a line is submitted.  To check that my assertion is correct, make a file like this:

```
echo -n 1 2 3 > /tmp/stuff.txt
```

Now double-check that no terminating newline is in the file

```
cat /tmp/stuff.txt
```

You'll notice that lack of a newline.  Now run your program - which works fine - against the file

```
./a.out < /tmp/stuff.txt
```

It worked fine.

Comment: Thanks John, you're right for the first two steps. But how do I do the last step?

Comment: Right, the last step assumes that your program is called a.out, the default output program name when you don't use -o on your c++ command line.  Just use whatever program name that you already use instead of a.out.  Hopefully, it all works, and you can hit this as an approved answer, thanks.

Comment: Thanks John, I was able to run it now.